# selenium grid, creating node programmatically

Tags: selenium, grid, registration, nodes

I have to create a java application that will start a node and connect it to the hub. So far I have been able to do so when the hub and node are on the same computer, but as soon as I try to connect on another machine hub, the registering process hang forever.

I tried different approach. To just call my bat file function in code.

```
String command = "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.26.0.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.0.11:4444/grid/register -port 4449 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=data\\driver\\chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=data\\driver\\IEDriverServer.exe -nodeConfig data\\configurations.json";

    try
    {
        pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The command work when called from a bat file, but in code it only works if the node and hub are on the same computer.

I also tried to use the RegistrationRequest.

```
RegistrationRequest req = new RegistrationRequest();
                req.setRole(GridRole.NODE);

                Map<String, Object> nodeConfiguration = new HashMap<String,
                Object>();

                nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.AUTO_REGISTER, true);
                nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.HUB_HOST, "192.168.100.66");

                nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.HUB_PORT, 4444);
                nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.PORT, 5555);

                URL remoteURL = new URL("http://" + "192.168.100.66" + ":" + 5555);
                nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.PROXY_CLASS, "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy");
                nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.MAX_SESSION, 1);
                nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.CLEAN_UP_CYCLE, 2000);
                nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.REMOTE_HOST, remoteURL);
                nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.MAX_INSTANCES, 1);

                req.setConfiguration(nodeConfiguration);

                remote = new SelfRegisteringRemote(req);
                remote.startRemoteServer();
                remote.startRegistrationProcess();
```

Same result, when I try to run on another computer hub, it hand at the registering process.
INFO - Registering the node to hub :http://192.168.100.66:4444/grid/register

any idea why? or how to do it.

Comment: I figured out my problem, which is really simple to fix. In my code I had

URL remoteURL = new URL("http://" + "192.168.100.66" + ":" + 5555);

I just needed to replace the ip address by my local ip address, not the hub ip address, and it worked. Which is weird cause I am pretty sure I took this code from somewhere online and he had a variable for the ip, and it was the same for b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem, which is really simple to fix. In my code I had

```
URL remoteURL = new URL("http://" + "192.168.100.66" + ":" + 5555);
```

I just needed to replace the ip address by my local ip address, not the hub ip address, and it worked. Which is weird cause I am pretty sure I took this code from somewhere online and he had a variable for the ip, and it was the same for remoteURL and the HUB_HOST

Answer (score 0):

well. Not sure whether is suitable for you  but I'd like to share approach I use on my project. 
I've got remote machine with 192.168.4.52 IP and selenium stanadlone server running on it.
All selenium test suites I got locally.
So to run my selenium test suite on remote machine I simply use these settings in BaseSeleniumTest.java on my local machine:

```
....
@BeforeClass
    public static void firefoxSetUp() throws MalformedURLException {

          DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();


        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.4.52:4444/wd/hub"), capability);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
    }
    @Before
    public void homePageRefresh() throws IOException {

        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.get(propertyKeysLoader("login.base.url"));
    }


    @AfterClass
    public static void closeFirefox(){
        driver.quit();
    }
```

where string

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.4.52:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

indicates IP of machine which I want to run my selenium test siute on.
I'm starting server on remote machine with this command:
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.26.0.jar`  in cmd before I run my test suite.
Hope it be helpful for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the ip of the computer I will run my tests on, I really need to have a java program that will connect a node to my hub. Right now the only way I can do it is with a bat file, but I would really like it to be started programmaticaly (so I can hide the process in the system tray). And so far I am only able to do it when the hub and the node are created on the same computer.